# Mapping of user accounts to dates and sorted list of dates return a mapping of the indexes the dates by user are in the sorted dates list efficently

Tags: python, algorithm

I am duplicating Facebook's chat read receipt system. I wrote some basic code I think works. However my boss thinks it would be slow. I have no algorithms training. What is the most efficient way to return a mapping of indexes to numbers where the numbers are between two numbers in a sorted list and the index is the index of the first number in the between pair?

```
# Given say {"a": 3, "b": 10, "c": 7, "d": 19} and [1,5,15] return {0: ["a"], 1: ["b", "c"], 2: ["d"]}
def find_read_to(read_dates, message_dates):
    read_indexes_to_user_ids = {}
    for user_id in read_dates:
        for i, date in enumerate(message_dates):
            last_index = i + 1 == len(message_dates)
            next_index = -1 if last_index else i + 1
            if last_index or (read_dates[user_id] >= date and read_dates[user_id] < message_dates[next_index]):
                if i in read_indexes_to_user_ids:
                    read_indexes_to_user_ids[i].append(user_id)
                else:
                    read_indexes_to_user_ids[i] = [user_id]
                break
    return read_indexes_to_user_ids

find_read_to({"a": 3, "b": 10, "c": 7, "d": 19}, [1,5,15])
```

**Version using bisect module**

```
import bisect
def find_read_to(read_dates, message_dates):
    read_indexes_to_user_ids = {}
    user_ids, read_dates = zip(*read_dates.items())
    def find_between(read_date):
        answer = bisect.bisect_left(message_dates, read_date)
        answer -= 1
        if answer == -1:
            return None
        return answer
    indexes_for_read_up_to = map(find_between, read_dates)
    for i, index_for_read_up_to in enumerate(indexes_for_read_up_to):
        user_id = user_ids[i]
        if index_for_read_up_to is None:
            continue
        if index_for_read_up_to in read_indexes_to_user_ids:
            read_indexes_to_user_ids[index_for_read_up_to].append(user_id)
        else:
            read_indexes_to_user_ids[index_for_read_up_to] = [user_id]
    return read_indexes_to_user_ids

find_read_to({"a": 3, "b": 10, "c": 7, "d": 19}, [1,5,15])
```

Comment: There are a few things that can be done to make your algorithm more efficient, but if `message_dates` is large that inner loop is a killer. Take a look at the bisect module for a much more efficient way to do that search.

Comment: @PM2Ring thank you I edited my question with code that uses the bisect module